# how to add custom js function for codeigniter anchor while using table library

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

This is my code:

```
foreach($patients as $patient) {
    $this->table->add_row(++$i,
                          $patient->opd_no,
                          $patient->sname.', '.$patient->fname.' '.$patient->mname, 
                          strtoupper($patient->gender),
                          date('M d, Y', strtotime($patient->birth_date)),
                          $patient->address_no.' '.$patient->address_st.' '.$patient->address_brgy.' '.$patient->address_local.' '.$patient->address_province,
                          anchor('consultation/queue/'.$patient->pk_id, 'Initial', ar

    ray('class' => 'queue'))
);
```

I want to add it at the anchor.

EDIT:
ok so I added this hoping this will be a workaround:

```
anchor('#'.$patient->pk_id, 'Initial', array('class' => 'queue', 'rel' => 'ic'))
```

and tried using the rel attribute via jquery to call a function. Something like this:

```
$('a[rel=ic]').click(function() {});
```

But then a codeigniter error page shows up saying

> The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by
>   CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I found my workaround to this. Instead of using CodeIgniter's anchor, I instead use the native html hyperlink tag `<a>`:

```
"<a href='#' class='queue' id='init_d'>Initial</a>"
```

This is a lot easier to add a js using jquery and the former error does not show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

here is another option for you to use (pattern)

anchor('home/showpage','Show Page',array('onClick' => 'Inital()')